# How to install a certificate and a driver after that from install shield?

Tags: driver, installshield

How to install a certificate and a driver after that from install shield?

Hai..

I am working in  install shield 2013 proffesional.
I have created the installer for installing driver through the device driver wizard and it is working fine.

Now, I need to install a certificate(.cer) in trusted root  authority before installing the driver. 
How can I do this?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant way I know how to do this in InstallShield is to create a WiX merge module using the IIS extension to describe the certificate going into the local machine | trusted root store.   Then add this merge module to your InstallShield project.

The merge module will schedule a custom action called InstallCertificates after the base action InstallFiles.  So as long as your InstallShield Difx custom actions get scheduled after that you should be fine.

Comment: Haii chris. Thanks for the response,

Actaully I want to install certificate without any merge module. I am able to install the certificate with certmgr.exe command through scripting but for this
I need keep the certificate,certmgr.exe and setup in one directory. I want avoid this dependency, Currently the setup copies the all installattion files to
INSTALLDIR before installing the driver and I want to add one custom action(for installing certificates with certmgr.exe) just after copying the installation files 
and before installing the driver.

How can I do this..please help.

Comment: You could build the merge module, examine how it's constructed and then extract the custom action from the Binary table and then author it all into your own MSI.   The point is, rather then roll your own CA, take advantage of the work that was already done.  Work that properly considers install, rollback, commit, uninstall. A merge module is just like a .LIB in C/C++.  Once it's merged into the MSI you don't ship it or have any dependencies and/or disadvantages.

Comment: Hi Chris..  Thanks for the rep;y , now i need to associate an existing merge module with my installation Installshield.  Do you have any explanation for that. I checked some forums and all but did not get enough information.  Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: InstallShield has a tools | options | merge modules tab that specifies a module search path.  Once your msm is in scope, go to the redistributables view and add the module.  Associate it to the correct feature(s).  The last important step is to right click | properties and associate it to the correct directory table entry.

Comment: Thank You  very Much Christopher..  I want one more help. How to copy the files added in Project assistant to a Common files Folder without hard coding the path? Is there any relative name for the directory from which our components are added to project assistant. I mean names like INSTALLDIR, SYSDIR, ..etc. Muy aim is just to copy files added in project assistant to common files folder using Install script.  Please Help.

Comment: Hi Chrishtopher.. Actually I asked for the Relative name not for COMMONFILESFOLDER but for the the source folder , i.e from where am copying files to common files folder.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for my own question:

1) Create a installshield Project (Installscript MSI Project)
2) Use Project->Device Driver Wizard for adding the .inf file 
3) Now in Install Designer->Behaviour and Logic->Installscript you will get your .inf file (as custom action : Top of the Install script edit

window). You need to install the certificate in the event before driver is insatlling.

Note:
You can copy file to any directory using API Xcopyfile()